# Getting `Error: [$parse:ueoe]` when try to compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create some dom from javascript code and bind it in angular context.
Example:

```
'<button ng-click="someFunction("123abc")">CLICK</button>'
```

When there is no parameter like `someFunction()` everything works fine
but when I add parameter I get error:

```
"Error: [$parse:ueoe]....ng-click="someFunction(" 123abc")"="" ...
```

How can I force angular to compile function with parameter?

Comment: `'<button ng-click="someFunction(\"123abc\")">CLICK</button>'`

Comment: No. Still getting the same.

Comment: why is this html element written in quotes? is it a PHP echo?

Comment: I create string `<button ng-click=....` and later compile it. I create this code in `for` loop. And it works fine withouth parameter but as soon as I add parameter it stop work.

Comment: try apostrophes `'<button ng-click="someFunction(\'123abc\')">CLICK</button>'` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
'<button ng-click=\'someFunction("123abc")\'>CLICK</button>'
```